# Как сделать отдельный подсчет "Count" для каждого из блоков?

Tags: jquery

Пример кода по ссылке - https://jsfiddle.net/rwtvmuyb/

```
$('.btn-count').click(function(e) {
  event.stopPropagation();

  var button_classes, value = +$('.product_price-input').val();
  button_classes = $(e.currentTarget).prop('class');
  if (button_classes.indexOf('up_count') !== -1) {
    value = (value) + 1;
  } else {
    value = (value) - 1;
  }
  value = value < 1 ? 1 : value;
  $('.product_price-input').val(value).trigger('change');
});
```

P.S. блоков с класом "product-block" на странице будет много.

Comment: для начала возьмите каждый блок в отдельную переменную а затем проверьте в каждом количество...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы меняете состояние всех инпутов на странице разом из-за группового селектора `$('.product_price-input')`

Вот так можно обратиться к предыдущему элементу, коим является инпут по отношению к якорю, на котором висит слушатель и на который мы кликаем:

```
 $(e.currentTarget).prev()
```

---

Вот, я слегка измени Ваш код для того чтобы он корректно работал:

```js
$('.btn-count').click(function(e){
    event.stopPropagation();
    let i = $(e.currentTarget).prev();
    var button_classes, value = +i.val();
    button_classes = $(e.currentTarget).prop('class'); 
    if(button_classes.indexOf('up_count') !== -1){
        value = (value) + 1; 
    } else {
        value = (value) - 1;            
    }
    value = value < 1 ? 1 : value;
    i.val(value).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-block">
    <div class="product-description">
        <form class="ms2_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="216">
            <label> Count: <a class="down_count btn-count">-</a>
                <input type="number" name="count" class="product_price-input" min="1" value="1"> <a class="up_count btn-count ">+</a> </label>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="product-block">
    <div class="product-description">
        <form class="ms2_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="216">
            <label> Count: <a class="down_count btn-count">-</a>
                <input type="number" name="count" class="product_price-input" min="1" value="1"> <a class="up_count btn-count ">+</a> </label>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

берите инпут из соседей

```js
$("button").click(function(){
   var $i = $(this).siblings("input");     
   $i.val( +$i.val() + $(this).data("value") );   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <button data-value="-1">-</button>
   <input type="text" value="1"/>
   <button data-value="1">+</button>
</div>
<div>
   <button data-value="-1">-</button>
   <input type="text" value="1"/>
   <button data-value="1">+</button>
</div>
```